# How to improve refresh for Excel Data Connections?

Tags: excel, file, database-connection

Like many, I have spreadsheet that draws data from over 40 text files as data sources. The text files are from another app, and need to be periodically updated into Excel.

The set of data source files and spreadsheet need to be able to be duplicated and run on different systems. This is where the astonishing inability of Excel to support data import from the spreadsheet folder (or relative paths at all) becomes a big problem. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927531/relative-file-paths-for-excel-data-connections) mentions the issue but has no solution.

I developed a crude workaround for this (IMHO) fundamental flaw in Excel. Map your spreadsheet folder to a drive letter with SUBST. Then import the data from the SUBST drive letter. That drive letter and path will become part of the spreadsheet, buried deep in dialogs, and very inconvenient to update. So instead, whenever you copy or move the spreadsheet, re-create the SUBST to the current folder. Ugly, but effective.

**New Question:** Using this technique, when I open the spreadsheet and click Refresh to refresh from the data sources, I have to click "Import" on over 40 dialogs - one for each file. How can I automate that process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I discovered that under a data range properties, there is a setting for "Prompt for file name on refresh".  By unchecking that, it is no longer necessary to click import for every linked file. The properties for each linked data source must be adjusted individually. There doesn't seem to be any ability to multi-select data sources.