# Relative Paths within Excel for CSV imports

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook that auto-updates the worksheets from CSV files. These pull in the data from a hard coded folder (c:\temp\premiumreports\name_of_CSV_file.csv).

This method forces me to put everything into c:\temp\premiumreports everytime or if I send the file to a customer they have to create the same directory structure.

I would like to place my xlsx file into any folder (c:\report or the user's desktop) with the necessary CSV files and when I open the xlsx the data is imported automatically.

Current Workbook Connection
[image]

Answer (score 3):

If the work book file is always located in the same folder as the CSV file you can utilize the ActiveWorkbook.Path method to set a relative path.

Example assuming csv file name and connection name are the same:

```
Sub refreshMsgConnection()
    Dim csvFileName As String
    csvFileName = "msg_by_weeks.csv"

    Dim filePath As String
    filePath = ActiveWorkbook.path

    Dim conString As String
    conString = "TEXT;" & filePath & "\" & csvFileName

    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("msg_by_weeks").Ranges.Item(1).QueryTable
        .connection = conString
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

You may have to play with some of the settings based on your configuration such as delimiters etc.  If you're having trouble, record a macro while you setup a new connection with the desired format and then copy the settings in this sub.

If the file is not found, it will pop up a file selection box for the user to locate the desired file.

Comment: Finally got around to giving this a try and I'm getting an 1004 error. When you go to debug, I points to this line.

With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("msg_by_weeks").Ranges.Item(1).QueryTable

Comment: @ShawnFarmer you have to do it on a saved file otherwise `ActiveWorkbook.path` will be empty, causing 1004 error.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer!

You may find the current file path putting in any cell of your workbook the formula

```
=LEFT(CELL("filename",$A$1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",$A$1),1)-1)
```

name this cell somehow, let say "FilePath" and generate absolute path in query like

```
let
    FilePath = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="FilePath"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
    FullPathToFile1 = FilePath & "Name1.xlsx"
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(FullPathToFile1), null, true)
in
```

source: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Excel/Power-Query-Source-from-Relative-Paths/m-p/206267/highlight/true#M6836

Comment: <let 
         ......
in>

You can find it in:
select the table copied from the source; In the ribbon: Query tools;  Advanced editor

Comment: There should be comma at the end of each line