# Delete all queries in a workbook

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I am trying to write a sub to delete all queries in a workbook. I have got the code below:

```
Dim CN As Variant
Dim qTable As QueryTable



For Each CN In ThisWorkbook.Connections
    CN.Delete
Next CN

 For Each qTable In Sheets("Property Extract 1").QueryTables
qTable.Delete
Next qTable'
```

The connection deletion works fine but the queries remain. Any ideas how to delete all queries in a workbook?

I was planning to replicate the query deletion for 2 or 3 sheets.

thanks

Comment: Posting this for anyone else stumbling onto this thread. I had a ss that over time became unresponsive and it ended up being that all the connections from web scraping were bogging it down. I used the code in this thread to delete all connections and the issue was fixed. Hopefully, this helps others with similar issues.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First off, you cannot delete PQ Queries from VBA unless you are on Excel 2016/365. PQ is not exposed to VBA in earlier versions even when the add-on is installed. If you have the right version of Excel, you can delete the PQ Queries themselves just like you are clearing the connections:

```
Dim pq As Object
For Each pq In ThisWorkbook.Queries
    pq.Delete
Next
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add another loop to loop through sheets.

```
Dim cn
Dim qt As QueryTable
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each cn In ThisWorkbook.Connections
    cn.Delete
Next
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each qt In ws.QueryTables
        qt.Delete
    Next
Next ws
```

**Edit:** If you are adding using Query Wizard then perhaps you'd need modified code below.

```
Dim cn
Dim qt As QueryTable
Dim lo As ListObject
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each cn In ThisWorkbook.Connections
    cn.Delete
Next
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each qt In ws.QueryTables
        qt.Delete
    Next qt
    On Error Resume Next 'Ignore error if there's no query in table.
    For Each lo In ws.ListObjects
        lo.QueryTable.Delete
    Next lo
    On Error Goto 0
Next ws
```

Comment: Thanks but the queries still remain in the queries and connection list under the data tab.

Comment: @Chris Weird. I don't get such issues. What option are you using to create query in data tab?

Comment: @Chris Check the edited post. See if it gets you through.

Comment: lo.QueryTable.Delete throws an error, its strange because the variable lo is picking up my query2

Comment: @Chris it will happen if there's table without query. Unfortunately there's no direct way of detecting it so I've used `On Error Resume Next`. See edited code.

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer your question. I am using vba to add the query.

Comment: Unfortunately the revised code doesnt remove the queries. Is it possible that this is a bug?

Comment: @Chris I am not sure. Is it possible to upload file somewhere and post a link if information is not confidential? I will try to have a look.

Comment: Delayed response but the solution proved "querytables" didnt work. Queries did

Answer (score 2):

Clear all connection in activeworkbook without any error. you must convert the Object to as String in order delete all connections

```
Sub ClearQueries()
    Dim pq As Object
    Dim q As String
    For Each pq In ThisWorkbook.Queries
        q = pq
        ActiveWorkbook.Queries(q).Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I Excel 2016 I was able to select all by maintaining CTRL and clicking on each in the Workbook queries pane. Then right-click --> Delete.